# Javascript meal counter .toFixed plus add comma

Tags: javascript, count, counter, decimal

```
<script>
var START_DATE = new Date("January 01, 2013 00:00:00");
var INTERVAL = 0.25;
var INCREMENT = 0.001;
var START_VALUE = 0;
var count = 0;
function addCommas(str){
   var arr,int,dec;
   str += '';

   arr = str.split('.');
   int = arr[0] + '';
   dec = arr.length>1?'.'+arr[1]:'';

   return int.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g,"$1,") + dec;
}window.onload = function(){
 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
 var now = new Date();
 count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = addCommas(count);
 setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML =     addCommas(count);", msInterval);
}
</script>
<div id="counter"> 30k</div>
```

Where would I have to put .toFixed(2) in order for our non-profit organization's meals served counter to only show two places after the decimal. I tried many different places but am unsure .toFixed is even the right solution. Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it in your `addCommas` function:

```
function addCommas(str){
    var arr,int,dec;
    str += '';

    arr = str.split('.');
    int = arr[0] + '';
    dec = arr.length>1?'.'+arr[1]:'';
    return int.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g,"$1,") + '.' + parseFloat(dec).toFixed(2).split('.')[1];
}
```

Comment: I tried this second and it is a brilliant and speedy solution!

Answer (score 1):

If I run:

```
count = 12345678.912;
formatted = count.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.\d\d$)/g,"$1,");
```

formatted has the string

```
12,345,678.91
```

as its value.

I think that does what you wanted, and somewhat more simply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function addCommasWithDecimal(nStr, decPlcs) {
    nStr = parseFloat(nStr).toFixed(decPlcs);
    nStr += '';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1))
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Comment: I tried this first but it didn't render a count inside the div